# Combine two regular expressions into one, matching first and last part of URL?

Tags: php, regex

How can I combine two regexes?

For example, I have this string:

/path/to/file/name.jpg

I want to match two parts of this string with only one regex, so that I can have "/path/to/file/" (everything but last part of url) and "name.jpg". Is it possible?

Edit: I know there are other ways of doing this using PHP functions, but I need to do it with Regex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('#^(.*?/)([^/]+)$#', $path, $matches))
{
    list($all, $directory, $filename) = $matches;
}
```

Even though there are specific functions like `pathinfo()` `dirname()` and `basename()`

Answer (score 1):

In this special case I would not use a regex at all. Use:

```
$path = dirname('/path/to/file/name.jpg');       // /path/to/file
$filename = basename('/path/to/file/name.jpg');  // name.jpg
```

If you need a regex, use something like this:

```
$str = 'path/to/file/name.jpg';
$pattern = '~(.*)(/.*)~';

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
$path = $matches[1];
$filename = $matches[2];
```

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it as PHP but I really need to do this with Regex, because I'll actually use a similar code in a .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok, currently preparing regex example. give me a minute

Comment: So are you trying to write a mod_rewrite rule? If so, please ask another question and delete this one.

Comment: ... I would not delete it. as it is good for other purposes as well

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$foo = '/path/to/file/name.jpg';
$bits = pathinfo($foo);
print_r($bits);
```

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => /path/to/file
    [basename] => name.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => name
)
```

Comment: Hey man thanks, I know I can do this in another way with PHP, but I really need to do with Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible:

```
/^(?P<path>.*?)(?P<filename>[^\/]*)$/
```

[phpfiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dsq-hb4)

Comment: its funny how everyone wants to show off their regex skills ;) love the named groups feature +1

Comment: @MarZab everyone tries to be helpful :)